# getting error Ora - 01722: invalid number for sum of two columns with number type in where condition

Tags: ora-01722

For my query I am getting Ora - 01722: invalid number for below condition, where both col1 and col 2 have type number(17,2).

WHERE col1 + col2 <> 0

And this query works very fine - WHERE col1 + col2 = 0

Can someone please help here?

Comment: The query is working fine in 11g but not in 12c

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting `WHERE col1 is null or col2 is null` and see if either can be null?

If that's the case, perhaps you need to select where `col1 is not null and col2 is not null` or use the `NVL` function:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I already tried with **NVL** clause as well as with not null predicates. But no resolution